# Error installing php5-mcrypt

Tags: php, ubuntu, server, google-compute-engine, mcrypt

Just today I signed up with Google Cloud Compute Engine. I did everything but then I stuck into an error while installing `php5-mcrypt` extension. 
Error:

```
root@instance-2:~# sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5-mcrypt : Depends: phpapi-20121212
               Depends: php5-common (= 5.5.24+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~vivid+1) but 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I searched everywhere and then I came here. Please help.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Answer (score 3):

sudo service apache2 restar

```
apt-get install php5-common
```

Or, if you dont need to keep configurations:

```
apt-get purge php5-common
apt-get install php5-common
```

---

**Do you get any output from `apt-mark showhold`?**

If it does not solve your problem, you should try install it with aptitude:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude install php5-mcrypt
```

---

**Finally reatast the server**

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: what is your ubuntu version?

Comment: php5-mcrypt : Depends: phpapi-20121212 which is a virtual package.
               Depends: php5-common (= 5.5.24+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~vivid+1) but 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6 is installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     php5-mcrypt [Not Installed]

Comment: Getting the same as @AdityaGiri . `php5enmod mcrypt` still does not work. Why is this reply accepted?

Comment: @3244611user did you try with aptitude?

Comment: Yes. And I got the same as @aditya : `Keep the following packages at their current version: 1) php5-mcrypt [Not Installed]` which is not what I desire, right? And hence I still could not activate it with php5enmod (it says that it could not find mcrypt). I had to purge apache2 first, then it even worked with apt-get, as stated in my solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is horrible, horrible, horrible. Adding `ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6` together with `ppa:ondrej/php5` and `ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable` will bring you nothing at all, as you need exactly one of these (as one contains PHP 5.4, second PHP 5.5 and third PHP 5.6). Purging `php5*` and `apache2*` is also not necessary, you might want to purge `apache2.2-common` if you encounter an error upgrading, but that's it. And then `mcrypt` and `curl` modules will get enabled automatically (unless you have disabled them in the past), so `php5enmod mcrypt` and `php5enmod curl` is extra (but not harmful).

Answer (score 0):

Had exactly the same problem. The accepted solution did not work for me. Took me eternities to figure a way.

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:ondrej/php5
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6
sudo apt-get purge php5* apache2* mcrypt*
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

(WARNING: You'll lose all settings for your PHP and Apache installation!)

reinstall:

```
sudo apt-get install php5 php5-mcrypt php5-curl apache2
```

and enable the extensions

```
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
sudo php5enmod curl
```

Magic.